# How to pass the parent page data to load the PartialView on ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

We have one Parent Page (DistributionReview.aspx) and it is having two tabs (DistributionByType and DistibutionByStatus).
The parent page is having a datetime textbox and trying to pass this date to the partialviewresult.

Wondering how to pass this data to the partialview?

```
<div id="container" >
<div> Select a Date: &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="fileDepositDate" name="datepicker"  /></div>
    <div id="divDistributionReview">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByType">Distribution Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="/DistributionReview/DistributionByStatus">Status</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

```
public ActionResult DistributionReview(string id)
    {
        var view = View(ApplicationConstants.DistributionReviewViewName, new MegaLockbox.Web.ViewModels.DistributionByTypeViewModel(securityManager, distributionReviewDataAdapter, id));
        return view;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DistributionByType(string id)
    {
        var view = PartialView(ApplicationConstants.DistributionByTypeViewName, new MegaLockbox.Web.ViewModels.DistributionByTypeViewModel(securityManager, distributionReviewDataAdapter, id));
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

attach a click event handler to the links and pass the date in Query String.

e.g. you can do such thing using jQuery like >

```
$("a").click(function () { 
   addr = $(this).attr("href");
   $(this).attr("href", addr + "?SelectedDate=" + $("#fileDepositDate").val();
});
```

and include `Date SelectedDate` in the Partial View Controller parameters